# conniption origin?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I viewed  the thread about conniption dido - which I'd  never heard before. But was wondering  what true meaning of conniption  was? I always figured  it was an old medical  term for seizure  or something.

Comment: Good question, though I fear we’re not likely to get an authoritative answer. When both etymonline and the OED give up and just like vague possibilities (an alleged dialect word _canapshus_ or a corruption of, well, _corruption_), our chances of outdoing them seem slim to me. But we have managed to get lucky in such regards before!

Comment: I don't think it's exactly an "old medical term" - more of a rather quaint AmE slang term for ***tantrum***, about on a par with "hissy fit". OED lists it as **US vulgar**, first recorded 1833.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117739/what-is-the-origin-and-meaning-of-conniption-dido

Comment: The question is unclear: The title asks for the origin. The body asks for the meaning.

Comment: @Josh61 That almost-duplicate is specifically asking about the _dido_ part, not _conniption_.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of "conniption" is "a fit of rage or hysterics."

The etymology of "conniption" is unclear. Many sources note that the first appearance of this word is in 1833 but no one has yet found the source of the word. There is a good, short review of this subject here:

http://etymologynow.blogspot.com/2010/03/etymology-of-conniption-fit.html

with a few more interesting details.